# How would I convert this query to one using sub queries?

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

How would I convert this block:

```
select p.ProductNumber, p.Name
from product as p, productsubcategory as ps
where p.ProductSubcategoryID = ps.ProductSubcategoryID
    and ps.Name = 'Pedals'
order by p.ProductNumber;
```

Into one that uses only subqueries instead of using two aliases for the databases?

Comment: The aliases are for tables and not databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses subqueries *and* keeps the aliases on the tables.  Table aliases are a good idea:

```
select p.ProductNumber, p.Name
from product p
where p.ProductSubcategoryID in (select ps.ProductSubcategoryID
                                 from productsubcategory ps
                                 where ps.Name = 'Pedals'
                                )
order by p.ProductNumber;
```

Note:  your original query is fine except that it should use explicit `join` syntax and not an implicit `join` in the `where` clause.